# How do I programatically search Google Plus for posts via the PHP library

Tags: php, api, google-plus

I'm trying to get my head around how to use Google's PHP library to search Google Plus using the API.  I want to create a command line script that can be run regularly (cron job) to search Google Plus for a key word and then store the results in a database.  I will then have a website (moderation tool) that pulls the posts from the DB and allows the moderator to reply to the original poster (or not and delete's that post from the DB).

I can do this with curl on the public API but it feels dirty.  I want to use their API properly with OAuth2 but that involves a website for authentication.  I want to run it via a cron job php script at the command line.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that, although you can use OAuth2 to authenticate against the Google+ API, you don't really get anything from doing so. The only thing you can get right now are public posts.

So what you're doing is fine. If you still want to use PHP for some reason, you can take a look at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search#examples and select "PHP" in the pull down to see some example PHP code. If you're having trouble with this, post a question with details about what you've tried and what problems you're having with it.